# Information management policy setting via PowerShell

Tags: list, content-type

How to add `{_UIVersionString}` into information management policy setting via PowerShell?

I want to Add the UIVersionString for a content type in PowerShell, because I want to do this with all my sites in the tenant.

```
Library Settings -> IMPS --> Content type --> Enable Labels
```

[image]

Comment: HI Dennis please refer to these links and let me know if you have any questions. See: https://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2018/05/configuring-default-office-365-labels-using-powershell/ And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602542/update-azure-api-inbound-policy-from-powershell And: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sCOn8yIqNA